# How much to turn to make a circle?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

It's weird that I never thought about this before and it looks so simple. You are swimming in a lake (or maybe on a boat) and you have a compass or something with which you can measure the angle of your turns. How can you make a circle of radius $r$?

I just realize that we undergo a motion that's both rotational and transnational. Seems more like a physics question now.

Comment: How do you measure the angle of a turn?

Comment: The radius is related to the [curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature).

Comment: Transnational if and only if a boundary crosses the lake :)

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan I don't even know that. Let's just go with we can measure the angle turned on the boat's steering or just how much you steer the boat towards the left/right.

Comment: @charlesh Instead of the angle, you should focus on the curvature of the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pure mathematical question, and the answer is simple: with just a compass you can not even make sure to draw a circle. At best, a convex spiral (not necessarily closed).

---

If you add the condition that you are able to swim in a perfectly regular way (?), you can indeed follow a circle. Of unknown radius. (More precisely, with an angular deviation always proportional to the swimmed distance.) But then a compass is of no use.

Comment: And if one has not only compass but also a straight-edge? :)

Comment: @user: neither. (A straight-edge is not meant to have tick marks.) It would be of no help at all.

Comment: (+1) Seems interesting. Is there a more concrete reason to back your claim?

Comment: @charlesh: I return the question (I cannot tell you how to "not do it"): how would you proceed to swim in a circle with the sole help of a compass ?

Comment: Makes sense. Is there a way we can make a circle of a radius of our choice given that there's no propeller and something that sets direction (like in a ship or a car where you fix a pair of wheel and keep another pair rotated)? (Basically I don't want that imaginary pivot (and a circle) that exists when we turn a car/ship.

Comment: @charlesh: I answered, didn't I ?

Comment: I don't think so or if you did, it wasn't convincing enough. And for the straightedge question, even if it had ticks, we would be requiring the imaginary pivot/circle to back us.

Comment: @charlesh: show me your solution and I'll tell you why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can measure velocity: just keep the angular deviation per time unit by the value:
$$
\omega=\frac vr,
$$
where the angle is assumed to be measured in radians.